# Got problem to retrieve the edit text value entered in other activity

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner of Java. Since I wanted to retrieve back the EditText value from Expenses class, I used the `Intent Class` to store the data and then retrieve it in the `Result` class. But when I run the Eclipse program, it stops.

**Expenses class**

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Add",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
    int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(s.equals("Food")){
            value = et1.getText().toString();
            food = Integer.parseInt(value);
            description = et2.getText().toString();
            categorySelected = true;
            i.putExtra("eFood",food);
            et1.getText().clear();
            et2.getText().clear();
        }
}
```

**Result class**

```
TextView tv;
int eFood;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    eFood = i.getIntExtra("eFood",0);
    tv.setText(eFood);
}
```

Comment: Where is intent? Where is _startActivity()_?. Also _tv.setText(eFood);_ should be  `tv.setText(eFood+"");`

Comment: show the whole class

Comment: where are you starting the `Result ` activity?

Comment: are you sure `textView2` exists?

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace (error message) you get from when the app crashes?

Comment: Thank you for willing to help, the answer below had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assign an integer to setText. Convert it to a String before assigning.

```
String efoodStr = "" + eFood;
tv.setText(efoodStr);
```

```
TextView tv;
int eFood;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    eFood = i.getIntExtra("eFood",0);
    String efoodStr = "" + eFood;
    tv.setText(efoodStr);
}
```

Comment: if it works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I think the answer below is of much more benefit.

Comment: @AryeeteySolomonAryeetey just for asking, if I got 3 activity. Activity 1 using intent to jump to Activity 2, and Activity 2 jump to Activity 3. Then, my Activity 3 can retrieve the data from Activity 1 since Activity 1 intent is not jumping to Activity 3?

Comment: you would have to get the data in ***Activity 2*** and then send it to *Activity 3*

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing it this way:-

```
String hiString = "hi";
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
//Create the bundle
Bundle b = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
b.putString(“stuff”, hiString);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the resulting activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String text= bundle.getString("stuff");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no problem.Please upvote the answer if it is helpful or please accept it.thanks